# How to rerender parent when child component value changes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component structure that can be used like in this example

**usage.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <c:parent>
        <c:child />
        <c:child />
    </c:parent>
</aura:component>
```

Where the parent modifies attributes of the childs on init and later on other actions

**parentController.js:**

```
({
    init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        cmp.get("v.body").forEach(function(child) {
            ...
            child.set("v.css", "stateDependingClass");
        });
    },

    otherAction: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        cmp.get("v.body").forEach(function(child) {
            ...
            child.set("v.css", "stateDependingClass");
        });
    },
})
```

**parent.cmp:**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="children" type="Aura.Component[]" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.children}" var="child">
        <div class="{!'otherClass ' + child.css}"> <--- THIS DOESN'T GET RERENDERED
            ...
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

The problem is that the change in the childs attribute is not reflected in the UI. It not seems to be rerendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local iteration variable "child" is a real component reference and therefore the [API for components](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Component) apply resp. LockerService will enforce it. I think it's not possible accessing attributes in a manner like `child.get("v.css")` in an expression.

Did I understand it right that you don't want to have the visualization (the div with the class expression) inside the child component - rather you try only using certain kind of data stored in the child without visualizing it? If so, you could create an own array-like attribute in the parent reflecting the order of all your children and storing all kind of data you are interested in the iteration.